# Validating date has expired with current system date

Tags: sql

I am trying to compare the database stored date value with the current system date. The date format is (YYYY-MM-DD). and the sql date i written compare is as follows.

`select id from table1 where tabel1.date > current_date`

And i want to get result if the date has been expired or not.

Please find me the correct sql.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, when `tabel1.date > current_date` the date stored in your database is in the future.

Try

```
select id from table1 where tabel1.date < CURDATE();
```